# Merging ontologies in OWLAPI with same IRI's

Tags: jena, owl, owl-api

I generally keep my ontologies in two different files.

1. First ontology file contains the classes, subclasses, data properties and object properties.
2. The second file containing all the individuals and relationships between the individuals.

So, I need to merge these two files in order to have a complete model. I wonder how this could be achieved using owlapi?

In Jena, I do this as follows:

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM,
                null);
try {
        model.read(new FileInputStream(MyOntologyFile), "...");
        model.read(new FileInputStream(MyOntologyWithIndividualsFile), "...");
} catch (Exception e) { 
        log.error("Loading Model failed:" + e);
}
```

In the similar fashion when I tried to load my ontology files using owlapi, I get error:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLObjectRenderer renderer = new DLSyntaxObjectRenderer();

File file = new File(MyOntologyFile);
File fileIndividuals = new File(MyOntologyWithIndividualsFile);

OWLOntology localOntology = null;
// Now load the local copy
try {
    localOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
    localOntology = manager
            .loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(fileIndividuals);
} catch (OWLOntologyCreationException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error:

```
org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyAlreadyExistsException: Ontology already exists. OntologyID(OntologyIRI(<http://www.semanticweb.org/lp4220/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-35>))
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntology(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:880)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:806)
    at uk.ac.manchester.cs.owl.owlapi.OWLOntologyManagerImpl.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(OWLOntologyManagerImpl.java:821)
```

---

### Update:

As it turns out, merging of ontologies is only possible with those having different IRI's, and hence I presume it is not acceptable to divide an ontology into two with the same IRI. A solution for this (as commented by Joshua) may be to read all individuals and axioms from one ontology and then add them to an already loaded ontology.

For ontologies with distinct IRI's merging can be done as follows (example courtesy Ignazio's [OWLED 2011 slides - slide no. 27](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/owled2011_tutorial.pdf)):

```
OWLOntologyManager m = create();
OWLOntology o1 = m.loadOntology(pizza_iri);
OWLOntology o2 = m.loadOntology(example_iri);
// Create our ontology merger
OWLOntologyMerger merger = new OWLOntologyMerger(m);
// Merge all of the loaded ontologies, specifying an IRI for the
new ontology
IRI mergedOntologyIRI =
IRI.create(
"http://www.semanticweb.com/mymergedont"
);
OWLOntology merged = merger.createMergedOntology(m,
mergedOntologyIRI);
assertTrue(merged.getAxiomCount() > o1.getAxiomCount());
assertTrue(merged.getAxiomCount() > o2.getAxiomCount());
```

Comment: Do those files have ontology headers?   You probably just want to load one ontology, then load the other, and then add all the axioms from one to the other.

Comment: Yes, they do have ontology headers. In fact, the two files are exactly the same except for the fact that the second contains the individuals with relations. I get your point on adding axioms to other. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not having the same iri in the data but ontologies with the same iris loaded in the same manager. Load the ontologies in separate managers and add all the axioms from one to the other, that will give you a merged ontology.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you do not make "Individuals and Relationships" an Ontology, unless they require for classifications - say to define Class "American Company" you need an Individual "US". Otherwise, that other part is should be your RDF triples that refer to the Ontology.